# Python - Coordinates of an array

Tags: python

I'm sorry, I think this is a really trivial question, but...

I have a binary Numpy array, mostly zeros with a few ones. I would like to find the coordinates of all the locations where `myArray[myArray == 1]`

Please can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: "Array"? List of lists? Numpy array?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're creating `myArray`, but this could work: `[i for i,v in enumerate(myArray) if v == 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.where(myArray==1)
```

I guess, should work (assuming its numpy array, based on your indexing example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a list (rather than a numpy array), this answer uses enumerate in both a loop and list comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202481/1160876